# Не работает hover на другой блок

Tags: html, css

Пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы при наведении на текст выводилась подсказка. Но hover не работает конкретно на этот тэг.

```css
.rabota:hover .rezhim {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: .5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-3 rz ">
  <p>ул.Кирова, 65<br><span class="rabota">Режим работы</span>
  </p>
  <div class="rezhim">
    <span>пн-пт: 09:00-20:00</span>
    <span>сб: 10:00-15:00</span>
    <span>вс: выходной</span>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема заключается в том, что ваша конструкция `.rabota:hover .rezhim` пытается найти блок с классом `rezhim` внутри блока с классом `rabota`, которого нет, так как он идет следующим в дереве.

Я предложил бы вынести ваш `span` за пределы `p` и использовать оператор `+`, который ищет следующий элемент после `.rabota` в данном случае.

```css
.rabota:hover + .rezhim {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: .5s;
}

.rezhim {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-3 rz ">
  <p>ул.Кирова, 65</p>
  <span class="rabota">Режим работы</span>
  <div class="rezhim">
    <span>пн-пт: 09:00-20:00</span>
    <span>сб: 10:00-15:00</span>
    <span>вс: выходной</span>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Потому что css - это каскад. Правила могут распространяться только сверху вниз: от родителя к детям либо от элемента выше на элемент ниже. А Вы пытаетесь из спана, вложенного в абзац, достучаться до дива, лежащего на другом уровне (на уровень выше).

Задайте `class="rabota"` абзацу и слегка измените правило в css:

```css
.rezhim {
  opacity: 0;
}
.rabota:hover ~ .rezhim {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: .5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-3 rz ">
  <p class="rabota">ул.Кирова, 65<br><span>Режим работы</span>
  </p>
  <div class="rezhim">
    <span>пн-пт: 09:00-20:00</span>
    <span>сб: 10:00-15:00</span>
    <span>вс: выходной</span>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Ваш код говорит "при наведение на блок `.rabota` используем правила для **вложенного** `.rezhim`", ну внутри `.rabota` нет никакого `.rezhim`, он лежит на уровень выше, **по этому и не работет**.

Как вариант, повесить `:hover` на элемент `p`, и брать элемент рядом `.rezhim`:

```css
.rezhim {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s;
}

.hover:hover ~ .rezhim {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-3 rz ">
  <p class="hover">ул.Кирова, 65<br><span class="rabota">Режим работы</span>
  </p>
  <div class="rezhim">
    <span>пн-пт: 09:00-20:00</span>
    <span>сб: 10:00-15:00</span>
    <span>вс: выходной</span>
  </div>

</div>
```